# Shared windows form application between different projects

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a Windows Form C# application to fill a certain form (convert excel to xml). This part of the product is the same for all the clients. But some other clients need an analytics processing unit for the software which is analysing an Excel file (and then creates the required excel which is then converted to xml) and fill the form according the processed data with the "form filling application".

I don't want to be the form filling and the analytics processing "modules" to be separate executables. The form filling module is the same for every client, but the analytics processing module can be totally different client by client. The idea is that you can start the analytics processing from the form filling module with a button. (The analytics processing module doesn't need to have any windows forms but the errors detected by the software should be display in a datagridview in order to be correctable by the user).

Which is the best way to handle this? How can I use the same form filling module with different analytics modules?

Comment: Make "form filling module" as separated assembly. Create executable project which used "form filling module" only. Then create own executable project which reference "form filling module" and have own implementation of "analytics module".

Comment: this method will result in one executable or two?

Comment: this method will result in one executable